# How can I check in JavaScript if a DOM element contains a class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, htmlelements

How can I check in JavaScript if a DOM element contains a class?

I tried the following code, but for some reason it doesn't work...

```
if (document.getElementById('element').class == "class_one") {
    //code...
}
```

Comment: [`class` is reserved as a future keyword by the ECMAScript specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words). Also, what if the element has more than 1 class?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To get the whole value of the class atribute, use `.className`

[From MDC:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classname)

> className gets and sets the value of the class attribute of the specified element.

## Since 2013, you get an extra helping hand.

Many years ago, when this question was first answered, `.className` was the only *real* solution in pure JavaScript. Since 2013, [all browsers support](http://caniuse.com/#search=classlist) `.classList` interface.

JavaScript:

```
if(document.getElementById('element').classList.contains("class_one")) {
    //code...
}
```

You can also do fun things with `classList`, like `.toggle()`, `.add()` and `.remove()`.

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).

Backwards compatible code:

```
if(document.getElementById('element').className.split(" ").indexOf("class_one") >= 0) {
    //code...
}
```

Comment: it is 2016, I can use classList, awesome :)

Comment: Welcome to the future, @alwe

Answer (score 16):

The property you need is `className`, not `class`. Also, an element can have many classes, so if you want to test if it has a particular class you need to do something like the following:

```
function hasClass(el, clss) {
    return el.className && new RegExp("(^|\\s)" +
           clss + "(\\s|$)").test(el.className);
}

var element = document.getElementById('element');
if ( hasClass(element, "class_one") ) {
    // Do stuff here
}
```

**UPDATE**

Modern browsers (pretty much everything major except IE <= 9) support a `classList` property, as mentioned in @Dropped.on.Caprica's answer. It therefore makes sense to use this  where available. Here's some example code that detects whether `classList` is supported by the browser and falls back to the regex-based code otherwise:

```
var hasClass = (typeof document.documentElement.classList == "undefined") ?
    function(el, clss) {
        return el.className && new RegExp("(^|\\s)" +
               clss + "(\\s|$)").test(el.className);
    } :
    function(el, clss) {
        return el.classList.contains(clss);
    };
```

Comment: +1, was about to post something like that. Just one thing, I guess you have to pass a class name (`"class_one"` is the one that the OP wants to check) in your `if (hasClass(...))` example.

Answer (score 6):

All modern browsers support the `contains` method of [**`Element.classList`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) :

```
testElement.classList.contains(className)
```

---

#### Demo

```js
var testElement = document.getElementById('test');

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify({
    'main' : testElement.classList.contains('main'),
    'cont' : testElement.classList.contains('cont'),
    'content' : testElement.classList.contains('content'),
    'main-cont' : testElement.classList.contains('main-cont'),
    'main-content' : testElement.classList.contains('main-content')
}, null, 2) + '</pre>';
```

```html
<div id="test" class="main main-content content"></div>
```

---

#### Supported browsers

[image]

(from [**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist))

---

#### Polyfill

If you want to use [**`Element.classList`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and you also want to support ancient browsers like IE8, consider using [**this polyfill**](https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js) by [**Eli Grey**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78436/eli-grey).

Answer (score 5):

It's the [`.className` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classname), like this:

```
if (document.getElementById('element').className == "class_one") {
    //code...
}
```

Comment: @tereško - what is incorrect about this answer?  Keep in mind the question being asked.

Comment: it assumes that tag has only single class (and, in case if you want to update it - has nothing about [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList)).

Comment: @tereško - the question was "How can I check the class of a DOM element?", not "How do I check if a DOM element has a class?"...that question is elsewhere.

Comment: @tereško - classList doesn't work until IE10, it's not really a feasible option for most.  See here: http://caniuse.com/classlist

Comment: I would be tempted to change `==` to `===` just for completeness (also less ambiguity). Otherwise this old answer still remains true.

Comment: Well, `className` is *always* a string so it won't really make a difference. Unless you are jslint of course. ;)

Comment: @rlemon In what way is `==` ambiguous in this situation?

Comment: ambiguous may have been the wrong term. `==` forces me to think about coercion where there shouldn't be any. using strict equality is much more transparent for future you, or future developers looking at this statement. I wouldn't go so far as to say it is wrong, but I personally think in situations like this it shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 3):

A better solution than all of these (if you are using HTML5) is to use the classList API.

```
var element = document.getElementById('some-element');

if (element.classList.contains('class-you-want-to-check')) {
  console.log('element has target class')
} else {
  element.classList.add('class-you-want-to-check');
  element.classList.remove('class-you-want-to-check');
  element.classList.toggle('class-you-want-to-check');

  if (element.classList.contains('class-you-want-to-check')) {
    console.log('Yep, classList is baller')
  }
}
```

Comment: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/hidden-gems-of-html5-classlist/

Here's some documentation for you if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

toggleClass on element

```
var el = document.getElementById('element');
el.classList[['add','remove'][+el.classList.contains('class_one')]]('class_one');
```

or

```
el.classList.toggle('class_one');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then just this simple code will help:

```
if ($('.yourclass').length) {
  // do something
}
```

If you like to check more than 2 classes in the page then use  `$('.yourclass').length > 2`

Answer (score 0):

hasClass:

```
function hasClass(element, className) {
  return (element.className).indexOf(className) > -1;
}
```

containsClass:

```
function containsClass(element, className) {
  return Array.from(element.classList).filter(function (cls) {
    return cls.indexOf(className) > -1;
  }).length > 0;
}
```

[codepen demo](https://codepen.io/oezkany/pen/ydzeGx)

Comment: Watch out on hasClass: If an element has class „show-initial“ and you test for class „show“ you‘ll get true even if the element does not have the class.